# Difference between Action(arg) and Action.Invoke(arg)

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
    Action<string> myAction = SomeMethod;

    myAction("Hello World");
    myAction.Invoke("Hello World");
}

static void SomeMethod(string someString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(someString);
}
```

The output for the above is:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

Now my question(s) is

- What is the difference between the two ways to call the Action, if any?
- Is one better than the other?
- When use which?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

All delegate types have a compiler-generated `Invoke` method.
C# allows you to call the delegate itself as a shortcut to calling this method.

They both compile to the same IL:

#### C#:

```
Action<string> x = Console.WriteLine;
x("1");
x.Invoke("2");
```

#### IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldnull      
IL_0001:  ldftn       System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0007:  newobj      System.Action<System.String>..ctor
IL_000C:  stloc.0     
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     
IL_000E:  ldstr       "1"
IL_0013:  callvirt    System.Action<System.String>.Invoke
IL_0018:  ldloc.0     
IL_0019:  ldstr       "2"
IL_001E:  callvirt    System.Action<System.String>.Invoke
```

(The `ldnull` is for the `target` parameter in an [open delegate](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html))

Comment: So does it matter at all which method you call? There's no difference whatsoever?

Comment: No, they both compile to the same IL. One is shorthand for the other. The only *possible* benefit I can see is that you can check for null and call it using newer c# features when using `invoke`, e.g. `x?.Invoke("1")` will call the delegate only if it's not null.