# Is it conventional to say that functions are called and methods are invoked?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, oop, methods

I’m reading *Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist*. The author uses **“invoke”** with methods and **“call”** with functions.

Is it a convention? And, if so, why is this distinction made? Why are functions said to be **called**, but methods are said to be **invoked**?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (in a C# context): [What's the difference between “call” and “invoke”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18505422/464709)

Comment: In my experience with Python, I would say it is much more common to say/hear "call" for both methods and functions, and I have rarely heard "invoke" used for either. However, my training in Python is fairly informal, and you might have different conventions in different fields.

Comment: I've always differentiated that first order functions are always called. Methods of a class are invoked *on the class*

Comment: @cricket_007 interesting. Do recall at all how you picked up that convention? I am wondering if this came from the people/sources you learned from, habits from learning other languages etc..

Comment: @elethan Mostly just my language preference. Not sure if I really picked up anywhere in particular. In functional programming, it's really interchangeable. Say either one, and most people understand, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, maybe it is *easier* for new readers to make an explicit distinction in order to understand that their invocation is slightly different. At least that why I suspect the author might have chosen different wording for each.

There doesn't seem to be a convention that dictates this in the Reference Manual for the Python language. What I seem them doing is choosing *invoke* when the call made to a function is *implicit* and not explicit.

For example, in the Callables section of [the Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) you see:

> [..] When an instance method object is **called**, the underlying function (`__func__`) is called, inserting the class instance (`__self__`) in front of the argument list. [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine) Explicit call</sup>

Further down in [Basic Customization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) and specifically [for `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) you can see:

> **Called** to create a new instance of class `cls. __new__()` is a static method [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine) Explicit call</sup>

While just a couple of sentences later you'll see how *invoked* is used because `__new__` implicitly calls `__init__`:

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be **invoked**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine) Implicitly called</sup>

So no, no convention seems to be used, at least by the creators of the language. Simple is better than complex, I guess :-).

Comment: I should add that in Python, every call (except built-in data types, perhaps) includes attribute lookups, so there isn't even a distinction at implementation level.

Answer (score 2):

One good source for this would be [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). A simple text search through the section on Classes reveals the word **"call"** being used many times in reference to "calling methods", and the word **"invoke"** being used only once.

In my experience, the same is true: I regularly hear "call" used in reference to methods and functions, while I rarely hear "invoke" for either. However, I assume this is mainly a matter of personal preference and/or context (is the setting informal?, academic?, etc.).

You will also see [places in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sys.html?highlight=invoke#process-control) where the word "invoke" is used in refernce to functions:

> void **Py_FatalError**(const char *message)
>
> Print a fatal error message
> and kill the process. No cleanup is performed. **This function should
> only be invoked** when a condition is detected that would make it
> dangerous to continue using the Python interpreter; e.g., when the
> object administration appears to be corrupted. On Unix, the standard C
> library function abort() is called which will attempt to produce a
> core file.

And from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/refcounting.html?highlight=invoke#c.Py_DECREF):

> void **Py_DECREF**(PyObject *o)
>
> Decrement the reference count for object o. The object must not be NULL; if you aren’t sure that it isn’t NULL,
> use Py_XDECREF(). If the reference count reaches zero, the object’s
> type’s deallocation **function (which must not be NULL) is invoked**.

Although both these references are from the Python C API, so that may be significant.

## To summerize:

I think it is safe to use either "invoke" or "call" in the context of functions or methods without sounding either like a noob or a showoff.

Note that **I speak only of Python**, and what I know from my own experience. I cannot speak to the difference between these terms in other languages.