# Curried JavaScript - calling

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am admittedly a beginner with JavaScript, but I need to piece together someone else's code and I am having trouble understanding the following function and how to call it in node.

```
const invoke = method => object => object[method]
```

This obviously is a function that takes a method that returns another function that takes an object that then returns object[method], but what exactly is the purpose?  How would one use this?  Thank you.

Comment: `method` would be a string (property name). And actually there's no method invocation anywhere, it just returns the property value. Which might be a callable function, but it wouldn't be invoked as a method.

Comment: If you found this in some code, surely you also found examples where it is used? Can you post them, and/or link the source where you found this?

Comment: OK, so calling it would be something like `invoke("some method name")(object)`.  I'll try to see if it is used anywhere.

Comment: Yes. Probably more like `invoke("property")({property: 42}) == 42` than `invoke("method")({method(x) { return x+10; }})(0x20) == 42`

Comment: `invoke` is a terrible name for this function - A possible better name is `get` or `prop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way i see it is as the `const` states, it [invokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505422/whats-the-difference-between-call-and-invoke) a function stored in an `object` , 
as you mentionned, this can be broken down to :

```
const invoke = (method) => {    
    return (object) => {    
      return object[method] ;
    }
}
```

the goal of this i believe is that you can call it ( <strike>like you're telling a story</strike>  ) expressively and concisely : `invoke` the function `a` from the `functions` object. ( `functionnal-programming` )

from this [article about functional programming](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0)

> Functional programming is declarative rather than imperative, and
>   application state flows through pure functions. Contrast with object
>   oriented programming, where application state is usually shared and
>   colocated with methods in objects.

but the term `invoke` got me thinking about [Immediately invoked functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), so the usage of the `const invoke` can be :

getting function from the object ( without executing it ) not to have to instantiate the whole object and having the function in a variable and maybe manipulate it's `prototype`.

calling the function ( with parenthesis ).

getting a property from an object.

immediately invoke a function in an object.

```js
const myFns = {
  'a' : function(x){
    console.log(x || 'something to log when no params passed');
  },
  'b': {
    username : 'Doe'
  } 
}

const invoke = method => object => object[method]

let myFunction = invoke('a')(myFns); 
myFunction('hello from myFunction'); // call it or modify myFunction.prototype ... etc.

invoke('a')(myFns)('hello'); // simply call it 

let user = invoke('b')(myFns); // get a property
console.log(user.username);

(invoke('a')(myFns))(); // immidiatly invoke the function
```

<strike>probalby</strike> to avoid [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/eval) :P

Comment: Actually the name is really misleading. `invoke` does not invoke a function! It just accesses it. In your example, only the `…('hello')` actually calls the function.

Comment: So FP is about story telling? I am disillusioned.

Comment: i think the term can be used for `call` , check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505422/whats-the-difference-between-call-and-invoke , quote : `.. allows you to call an arbitrary method ...`

Comment: @ftor i think `story telling` is a bit overkill :P just to make a point , i meant `declarative rather than imperative` ( from the quote )

Comment: You should also mention that the arguments of a curried function can be supplied lazily one at a time, so that you can compose it with other functions (`comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))`) or use specialized intermediates (e.g. `const invokeFoo = invoke("foo")`.

Comment: [*On Storytelling*](https://www.deconstructconf.com/2017/evan-czaplicki-on-storytelling) by Evan Czaplicki (creator of Elm)

Answer (score 0):

The name 'invoke' suggests it should really be written like this:

```
const invoke = method => object => object[method]()
```

The `()` is the invocation. It's very general, so hard to say exactly how it would be used, but here's a silly example.

```
class Dog {
    speak () { console.log('woof') }
}

var dogs = [ new Dog(), new Dog(), new Dog() ];

dogs.forEach( invoke( 'speak' ) );

-> 'woof'
-> 'woof'
-> 'woof'
```

It's a pretty common pattern to let an array method like `forEach` do the second call of a higher-order function like this.