# My MoveTowards method is teleporting in Unity. I only want it to move slowly. What do I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, 2d

I am making a game when you gather but my MoveTowards method just teleports the object there or to the position I asked. I have made my own MoveTo method so here are my 3 scripts. One is an IUNit script which is an interface and holds the method MoveTo:

```
    using System;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IUnit 
{
    void MoveTo(Vector2 position, float stopDistance, Action onArrivedAtPosition);
}
```

Here is my Unit script which is where the AI goes:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class Unit: MonoBehaviour, IUnit
{
    public float speed;

    public void MoveTo(Vector2 position, float stopDistance, System.Action arrivedAtPosition)
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, position) >= stopDistance)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Then my GathererAI which activates my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Unit))]
public class GathererAI : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Transform treeNode;
public Transform storageNode;

public IUnit unit;

private void Start()
{
    unit = gameObject.GetComponent<IUnit>();

    unit.MoveTo(treeNode.position, 10f, null);
}

}
```

But the thing is it just teleports to the position without slowly moving. Please help?
Also, how do you start an action?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Comment: Maybe your `speed` is too high.  Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7907067/1092820)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MoveTo, you can try using a Rigidbody (rb), and do:

```
   public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed, acceleration;
    public Transform goHere;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        Vector3 direction = goHere.position - transform.position;
        direction = direction.normalized;
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(direction.x * speed, direction.y * speed);
        rb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, acceleration);
    }
```

Unless you don't want to use Rigidbodies, in which case, you should still have a target Vector (direction or location), and Lerp towards that position in a similar fashion ( Lerp = Linear interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

Here are your three scripts which I changed a bit to make it work.

IUnit.cs:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IUnit 
{
    void MoveTo(Vector2 position, float stopDistance, Action onArrivedAtPosition);
}
```

Unit.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Unit: MonoBehaviour, IUnit
{
    public float speed = 5;

    public void MoveTo(Vector2 position, float stopDistance, System.Action arrivedAtPosition)
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, position) >= stopDistance)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

GatheredAI.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Unit))]
public class GathererAI : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Transform treeNode;
public Transform storageNode;

public IUnit unit;

    private void Start()
    {
        unit = gameObject.GetComponent<IUnit>();

        // unit.MoveTo(treeNode.position, 10f, null);
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        unit.MoveTo(treeNode.position, 10f, null);
    }

}
```

Usually Vector2.MoveTowards is called in a repeating function, and yours was being called only once. And your speed may have been a bit too much for the distance that your body was supposed to travel, so it just teleported in that single call.

Also it won't be ideal to invoke an Action in this case because you are not finishing the complete movement in single call. To do that you will need to convert this MoveTo function to a coroutine maybe to loop over Vector2.MoveTowards and when the coroutine comes to an end then you simply call the action parameter as a function. It will simply call a callback function when your movement is done.

```
public void MoveTo(Vector2 position, float stopDistance, System.Action arrivedAtPosition)
{
    // your move logic here....
    arrivedAtPosition();
    //if you need to pass some argument say a bool, then change function parameter as "Action<bool> arrivedAtPosition" and call "arrivedAtPosition(true);"
}
```